# Conditionally ignore nunit testcase

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nunit

W.r.t. Nunit;
Is there a mechanism to conditionally ignore a specific test case?

Something in the lines of :

```
[TestCase(1,2)]
[TestCase(3,4, Ignore=true, IgnoreReason="Doesn't meet conditionA", Condition=IsConditionA())]
public voidTestA(int a, int b)
```

So is there any such mechanism or the only way to do so is to create separate test for each case and do Assert.Ignore in the test body?

Comment: Have you tried using Assert.Ignore()?

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.5.2

Comment: Thanks, updated the question with Assert.Ignore, although, I think, it would mean that we still create separate tests for each case (replicating the test body)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could add the following to the body of the test:

```
if (a==3 && b == 4 && !IsConditionA()) { Assert.Ignore() }
```

This you would have to do for every testcase you would want to ignore.
You would not replicate the testbody in this case, but you would add to it for every ignored testcase.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps test readability to minimize the conditional logic inside the test body. But you can definitely generate the tests cases dynamically using the testcasesource attribute on the test and in a separate method dynamically generate a list of test cases to run using the nunit testcasedata object.

So only the tests that you need to/ are valid to execute are run but you still have a chance to log etc the cases.

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.4