# Nunit :Skip test based on values pulled from configuration file

Tags: nunit, asp.net-core-3.1

Skip Nunit test based on values pulled from configuration file. I am using  appsetting.json for my configuration purpose

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014835/conditionally-ignore-nunit-testcase

Comment: no this does not helped